# HC 05 in debug mode

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a doubt related to HC 05 Bluetooth module. Actually, I am having one android app, using that app I just want to start communication between them. Which is doing properly. Now I want to check what is exact communication going on between HC 05 and android app?

Description :
In a simple manner, I want to know about Bluetooth protocol. If I pair HC 05 with my mobile then which command send by my mobile? If I send data to the HC 05 then which frame I received from Mobile App?

Basically, I am reading one BLE stack and working on BLE programming from last 2 week on one of the BLE module. But not able to understand their communication. So that's why I just want, Is there any way to put HC 05 in debug mode.

Thanks you,

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](https://github.com/akexorcist/Android-BluetoothSPPLibrary) link to know about the Bluetooth SPP Library.You can send the data to your hardware device and you can also implement listeners to listen to the data sent by the hardware device. 
I have used it many times to integrate my mobile app with another harware device using android bluetooth SPP protocol. 
Also, the data to send or receive depends on the way your hardware device is configured. Generally, you can check for some starting bytes as headers for receiving a particular info from the device.

Simple usage is as follows:

```
BluetoothSPP bt = new BluetoothSPP(yourContext);
//connect to device before sending data
bt.send("Message", true);
```